What function should I use to purchase a token transfer with program_id?
I am trying to repeat this transaction (4Ku7oqwPAwRLPm7jNp2oTigYv8XpcTPLJwF49dLVS6ypi35vH9orwRAPcfMj37jj8FwmpMFuP5j8cS1hwdoXJp67) programmatically on solana or solana cli (I will be grateful for any information).
I understand that it is worth creating a token account first (created).
Link to the transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/4Ku7oqwPAwRLPm7jNp2oTigYv8XpcTPLJwF49dLVS6ypi35vH9orwRAPcfMj37jj8FwmpMFuP5j8cS1hwdoXJp67

*programmatically on solana-python or solana cli

Since this transaction is interacting with program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P, you'll need to learn more about that program's implementation if you want to use it. Unfortunately there's no IDL published for it at https://solscan.io/account/6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P#anchorProgramIdl, so you'll need to dig around to learn more
